# UILabel doesn't update through modal presentation view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two class, **PresentViewController** and **ModalViewController**, In PresentViewController I call the ModalViewController in this format:

```
ModalViewController *targetController = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];

targetController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

targetController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentViewController:targetController animated:YES completion:nil];

// it is important to do this after presentModalViewController:animated:
targetController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 218);
```

In **ModalViewController**, I have a button who send a parameter to the class **PresentViewController**:

```
-(IBAction)apply{

    PresentViewController *infoViewController = [[PresentViewController alloc] init];
    [infoViewController setDiscount:[campoDesconto.text intValue]];

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

In **PresentViewController** the method **setDiscount** is as follows:

```
-(void)setDiscount:(int)value{

    NSLog(@"Method is called!");
    totalPrice.text = value;

}
```

This method is being called because I get a console message, but unfortunately this UILabel not updating your value, why this is happening and how can I solve?

Comment: If I understand what you're doing correctly, you're trying to get your modal view to change a value in your main view. To do so, you will need to set up a `weak` property or a delegate so that you can actually interact with your main view. You're just creating a new instance of your main view.

Answer (score 0):

That's because **totalPrice** is not probably instantiated before `setDiscount:` is called. Call `setDiscount:` after your view is loaded and **totalPrice** is instantiated to have the **label text** updated.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `apply` method, you haven't setup the `view` of `infoViewController` yet.
So you probably haven't created the `totalPrice` label yet, if you do `NSLog(@"totalPrice: %@", totalPrice);` in `setDiscount:`, it will probably output `(null)`. You should save the discount value as a property, and set it in `viewDidLoad` as well as when `setDiscount:` method is called.

You're also setting an `int` to a `NSString`, this isn't correct.

**PresentViewController.h**

```
@interface PresentViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) int discount;

@end
```

**PresentViewController.m**

```
@implementation PresentViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Setup detailLabel

    detailLabel.text = [@(self.discount) stringValue];
}

-(void)setDiscount:(int)discount
{
    _discount = discount;
    detailLabel.text = [@(_discount) stringValue];
}

@end
```

Comment: and if I told you, that the class PresentViewController not directly draws ModalViewController class, and to call this class is necessary that the User click a button within the existing PresentViewController class to execute the commands that call other class? This influences the response, or work the same way?

Comment: Whatever happens, if you access the `detailLabel` before its created it'll be `nil`. Also like I've said assigning an `int` to a `NSString` will not work either.

Comment: This command doesn't work for me... and the slog NSLog(@"totalPrice: %@", totalPrice); continue calling null

Comment: Update your answer to show your `viewDidLoad` method where you assign to the iVar for `detailLabel`, or are you using nibs?